# 404 Issue when going to the next year - php calendar

Tags: php, wordpress, calendar

I'm building a classic calendar for my website. But I have a big issue: a 404 error page when I navigate to the next year of my calendar. I've no idea to resolve that problem...

```
function draw_calendar($month,$year){
/*Some code for displaying calendar*/


$month = (int)  (isset($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
$year = (int)  (isset($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y'));

/* select month control */
$select_month_control = '<div class="form-group col-4"><select name="month" class="form-control" id="month">';
for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
    $select_month_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $month ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.ucfirst(strftime('%B',mktime(0,0,0,$x,1,$year))).'</option>';
}
$select_month_control.= '</select></div>';

/* select year control */
$year_range = 7;
$select_year_control = '<div class="form-group col-4"><select name="year" class="form-control" id="year">';
for($x = $year; $x <= $year+2; $x++) {
    $select_year_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $year ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.$x.'</option>';
}
$select_year_control.= '</select></div>';

/* "next month" control */
$next_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 12 ? $month + 1 : 1).'&year='.($month != 12 ? $year : $year + 1).'" class="control">Suivant >></a>';

/* "previous month" control */
$previous_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 1 ? $month - 1 : 12).'&year='.($month != 1 ? $year : $year - 1).'" class="control"><<  Précédent</a>';

/* bringing the controls together */
$controls = '<form method="get" class="form-row">'.$select_month_control.$select_year_control.' <div class="col-4"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-0" name="go" value="Choisir" /></div> </form>';


?>
<div class="row justify-content-between mt-5">
    <div class="col-3">
        <?php echo $previous_month_link;?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <?php echo $controls; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 text-right">
        <?php echo $next_month_link;?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
echo draw_calendar($month,$year);
    }
}
```

The error is an 404 error page with the following url : 
https://.../?month=1&year=2020&go=Choisir

Comment: Help us reproduce the issue. Please provide _properly formatted, working code_ and the steps needed to reproduce the issue. Currently, there is something wrong with your curly braces near the end.

Comment: Is the issue when you select from the dropdowns and submit the form?  Or is it when you click one of the navigation links?

Comment: I've tested your code and it seems to work fine. Is there maybe a CMS of framework that you're using? More importantly, if you remove "?month=1&year=2020&go=Choisir" - from the page where you see 404, are you on the same page that you submit the url from? Or maybe you got redirected to a different subtirectory somehow?

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
@Patrick : the issue appears both when I submit the form and with the navigation ilnks.

Comment: @Andrew : yes I'm using Wordpress and yes when I remove "?month=1&year=2020&go=Choisir" I go back to the page with the initial calendar

Comment: 404 errors are usually not code problems (in my experience). Code problems are usually 5xx errors. 404 specifically is usually what it says it is: you have link that goes somewhere it's not supposed to. As others have suggested, it could be a CMS problem doing some funky URL re-write stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on Wordpress, it seems like you're using reserved terms for $_GET variables:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms

Change the "year" to something like "y", and you should be good to go.

Comment: Awesome. It was the word "year".
Thank you !